# Ruby round float to_int if whole number

Tags: ruby, floating-point, int

In ruby, I want to convert a float to an int if it's a whole number.  For example

```
a = 1.0
b = 2.5

a.to_int_if_whole # => 1
b.to_int_if_whole # => 2.5
```

Basically I'm trying to avoid displaying ".0" on any number that doesn't have a decimal.  I'm looking for an elegant (or built-in) way to do

```
def to_int_if_whole(float)
  (float % 1 == 0) ? float.to_i : float
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the solution that ended up working the way I want it to:

```
class Float
  alias_method(:original_to_s, :to_s) unless method_defined?(:original_to_s)

  def is_whole?
    self % 1 == 0
  end

  def to_s
    self.is_whole? ? self.to_i.to_s : self.original_to_s
  end
end
```

This way I can update the `is_whole?` logic (I seems like tadman's is the most sophisticated) if needed, and it ensures that anywhere a Float outputs to a string (eg, in a form) it appears the way I want it to (ie, no zeros on the end).

Thanks to everybody for your ideas - they really helped.

Answer (score 55):

One simple way to it would be:

```
class Float
  def prettify
    to_i == self ? to_i : self
  end
end
```

That's because:

```
irb> 1.0 == 1
=> true
irb> 1 == 1.0
=> true
```

Then you could do:

```
irb> 1.0.prettify
=> 1

irb> 1.5.prettify
=> 1.5
```

Comment: Are there any ramifications to modifying a core class?

Answer (score 53):

A one liner sprintf...

```
sprintf("%g", 5.0)
=> "5"

sprintf("%g", 5.5)
=> "5.5"
```

Comment: How would you do something like `"#{%g, percentage}% off"`? Is it possible as a one-liner?

Comment: Not exactly, cause it drops not only `.0`, but also everything if the exponent is less than -4, and round it, for example: `"%g" % 1.123456789 # => "1.12346"`

Comment: Dennis, what you can do is the following:
`"#{format('%g', percentage)}% off"`  (`format` is a alias for `sprintf` and is preferable).

Answer (score 3):

I'm don't know much about Ruby.

But this is a *display* issue.  I would be extremely surprised if the libraries you are using don't have a way to format a number when you convert it to a string.

There might not be a catch-all formatting option that does exactly what you want but you could set up a method that returns true if the float is the float representation of a whole number and false otherwise.  Inside a formatting routine that you create (so you only have to do this in once place) just change the formatting based on if this is true or false.

[This](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/90277) discusses how to control the number of digits that appear after the decimal when displaying a number.

Watch out for the intricacies of floating point representations.  Math might say the answer is 3 but you may get 3.000000000000000000001.  I'd suggest using a delta to see if the number is almost an integer number.

Comment: This is true, but I want it to display this way *everywhere* a float outputs as a string.  Basically I want to override the Float.to_s method, or hang this logic on the end of it.

Comment: How would you use a delta in this case?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using rails you can use helper `number_to_rounded` with option `strip_insignificant_zeros`, for example:

```
ActiveSupport::NumberHelper.number_to_rounded(42.0, strip_insignificant_zeros: true)
```

or like this:

```
42.0.to_s(:rounded, strip_insignificant_zeros: true)
```

Answer (score 2):

Although I'd tend to agree with the above post, if you must do this:

```
(float == float.floor) ? float.to_i : float
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my horribly hacktastic implementation provided for educational purposes:

```
class Float
  def to_int_if_whole(precision = 2)
    ("%.#{precision}f" % self).split(/\./).last == '0' * precision and self.to_i or self
  end
end

puts 1.0.to_int_if_whole # => 1
puts 2.5.to_int_if_whole # => 2.5
puts 1.9999999999999999999923.to_int_if_whole # => 2
```

The reason for using the sprintf-style call is that it handles floating point approximations much more reliably than the Float#round method tends to.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Ruby either.

But in C++, I'd do this:

```
bool IsWholeNumber( float f )
{
    const float delta = 0.0001;
    int i = (int) f;
    return (f - (float)i) < delta;
}
```

And then I'd format the output precision based on that.